# How to send an error to streambuilder in flutter?

Tags: flutter, go, grpc

I am writing a chat application using gRPC protocol with a go server and a Flutter client. I have written a chat service that communicates with the server and creates a new connection whenever a new client connects and creates a new chatroom if they want to. I am trying to check if the chatroom number that the client wants is already in use then the flutter client should show an error to the user. I have written the code to return a gRPC error in the server if the chatroom number already exists. I am using a streambuilder to render the messages on screen and a generator function yields the messages from server.

I am not able to understand how to send the error from the receiveMessage method in chat_service.dart to the streambuilder in message_page.dart, so that I can render a AlertDialog with snapshot.hasError block.

**server.go**

```
func (s *Server) CreateStream(pcon *chatpb.Connect, stream chatpb.Broadcast_CreateStreamServer) error {
    grpcLog.Infoln("CreateStream called")
    conn := &Connection{
        stream: stream,
        id:     pcon.User.Id,
        active: true,
        error:  make(chan error),
    }
    chatroom := pcon.User.GetChatRoomNo()

    if pcon.WantsNewRoom {
        if _, ok := s.Connections[chatroom]; !ok {
            newConnection := []*Connection{conn}
            s.Connections[chatroom] = newConnection
            grpcLog.Infoln("New chatroom created")
        } else {
            grpcLog.Infoln("Chatroom already exists")
            return status.Errorf(
                codes.AlreadyExists,
                fmt.Sprintf("The Chatroom already exists"),
            )
        }
    } else {
        if _, ok := s.Connections[chatroom]; ok {
            s.Connections[chatroom] = append(s.Connections[chatroom], conn)
            grpcLog.Infoln("New user added to chatroom - ", chatroom)
        } else {
            grpcLog.Infoln("Chatroom does not exists")
            return status.Errorf(
                codes.NotFound,
                fmt.Sprintf("The Chatroom does not exist"),
            )
        }
    }

    // if _, ok := s.Connections[chatroom]; ok {
    //  s.Connections[chatroom] = append(s.Connections[chatroom], conn)
    // } else {
    //  newConnection := []*Connection{conn}
    //  s.Connections[chatroom] = newConnection
    // }

    return <-conn.error
}
```

**chat_service.dart**

```
  Stream<Message> recieveMessage({bool wantsNewRoom}) async* {
    print("RecieveMsg Called");
    print(user);
    Connect conn = Connect()
      ..user = user
      ..active = true
      ..wantsNewRoom = wantsNewRoom;

    await for (var msg in client.createStream(conn)) { //the error in this line from the server
      print("in the loop");
      yield msg;
    }

  }
}
```

**message_page.dart**

```
class MessagePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final ChatService service;
  final Int64 chatroomid;
  final bool wantsNewRoom;
  final String videoURL;
  MessagePage(this.service, this.chatroomid, this.wantsNewRoom, this.videoURL);
  @override
  _MessagePageState createState() => _MessagePageState();
}

class _MessagePageState extends State<MessagePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = TextEditingController();
    messages = Set();
    scrollController = ScrollController();
    _ytcontroller = YoutubePlayerController(
        initialVideoId: YoutubePlayer.convertUrlToId(widget.videoURL),
        flags: YoutubePlayerFlags(autoPlay: false));
  }

  Set<Message> messages;
  TextEditingController controller;
  ScrollController scrollController;
  YoutubePlayerController _ytcontroller;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Chatroom - ' + widget.chatroomid.toString()),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            YoutubePlayer(
              controller: _ytcontroller,
              showVideoProgressIndicator: true,
              progressIndicatorColor: Colors.amber,
              progressColors: ProgressBarColors(
                  playedColor: Colors.amber, handleColor: Colors.amberAccent),
            ),
            Flexible(
              child: StreamBuilder<Message>(
                stream: widget.service
                    .recieveMessage(wantsNewRoom: widget.wantsNewRoom),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasError) {    //I want to handle the error here
                    return Center(
                      child: AlertDialog(
                        title: Text("Error"),
                        content: Text(snapshot.error),
                        actions: <Widget>[
                          FlatButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                Navigator.pop(context);
                              },
                              child: Text("OK"))
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  }
                  if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                    return Center(child: Text("Start by typing a message"));
                  }
                  messages.add(snapshot.data);
                  return ListView(
                    controller: scrollController,
                    children: messages
                        .map(
                          (msg) => MessageBubble(
                            senderName: msg.id,
                            content: msg.content,
                            timestamp: msg.timestamp,
                            isMe: msg.id == widget.service.user.name,
                          ),
                        )
                        .toList(),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 3.0),
                    child: TextField(
                      controller: controller,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius:
                                  BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0))),
                          labelText: "Type a message"),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                  child: FloatingActionButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      widget.service.sendMessage(controller.text);
                      controller.clear();
                      scrollController
                          .jumpTo(scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent);
                    },
                    child: Icon(Icons.send),
                    backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
                  ),
                )
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: https://dart.dev/articles/libraries/creating-streams#using-a-streamcontroller - it has `sink.addError()` method

Comment: but actually why not to sent 2 kind of data: one with normal messages and another one with control data?

Comment: I am actually new to flutter and this is my first android project, I am mainly using flutter to create a client for my grpc server. I am not very sure about what sending 2 kinds of data on a stream means. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: And one more doubt, How do I attach a streamController to the stream returned by client.createStream?

Comment: @pskink...Thanks for the help.